# Not able to place and size TikZ figures side by side

Tags: subcaption

I am not getting correct results for placing TikZ files side by side:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}[l]{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \newlength\figureheight
      \newlength\figurewidth
      \setlength\figureheight{5cm}
      \setlength\figurewidth{8cm}
      %\input{a.tikz}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0.1,0) -- (0.9,0);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \subcaption{(a)}
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[l]{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \newlength\figureheight
      \newlength\figurewidth
      \setlength\figureheight{5cm}
      \setlength\figurewidth{8cm}
      %\input{b.tikz}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0.1,0) -- (0.9,0);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \subcaption{(b)} 
    \end{minipage}%
    \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1)welcome, (2) I assume they can actually fit next to each other. The width of your minipages might be to large, try 0.49 or 0.48 instead.

Comment: This Example can't work, as the included TikZ files are missing.

Comment: Also define those two length in the preamble not twice in the body

Comment: `\subcaption` is also undefined.

Comment: Is this question answered correctly? Or do you still have an issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need the package `subcaption`.
It is preferable to introduce lengths `figureheight` and `figurewidth` in the preamble such that you do not mess it up too much.
It might confuse that you called the subcaption the same way as their index.

If you still face an error it's probably inside your tikz figures.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}[l]{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \setlength\figureheight{5cm}
      \setlength\figurewidth{8cm}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0.1,0) -- (0.9,0);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \subcaption{(a)}
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[l]{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
        \setlength\figureheight{5cm}
        \setlength\figurewidth{8cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0.1,0) -- (0.9,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \subcaption{(b)} 
      \end{minipage}%
      \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}  

\end{document}
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: @Aishwarya Apte: Please tell me what is missing or accept the answer! (You will get reputation for accepting the best answer.)